# Combobox in Grid Delphi Object Pascal

Tags: delphi

Looking for a component or easy way to have a grid with 1 column strings and the other combobox.

Answer (score 2):

You can also VirtualStringTree, which is a very powerful component that can do both checklist grids along with the ability to assign any editor (even a combobox) to a specific column cell.

Comment: +1 Works fine. Didn't get the checkbox to work as nicely as the combobox though. Based on a tab of the "advanced" demo

Comment: Descendant of Virtual TreeView, look here: http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33

Answer (score 1):

its not free, but TProfGrid from www.profgrid.com is incredible. it has support for combobox (among other things) in grid cells.

-don

Comment: In fact, any TControl descendant. Only problem I have had with it is major interface changes between versions. Also has export to Excel and word (via OLE) and support for merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

if you can spend a few dollars you can check the [TMS Grid Pack](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/gridpack.asp)

[image]

Otherwise check the [kgrid](http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kgrid.html) component, wich is part of [KControls](http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kcontrols.html) , is freeware.

[image]

Also you can check the [grid section](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=117) of  [Torry Delphi Pages](http://www.torry.net/index.php)